# Improve a java soap client

Tags: java, xml, soap

I have a java soap client that sends XML requests to a distant server and gets the responses.
It works but it takes too much time to send and retrieve the result from the server. 
Is there a way to speed up my soap client ? setting a timeout to zéro something like that ?

Here is the code for my soap client :

```java
public class SoapHelper
{

  public String server = "";
  public String username = "";
  public String password = "";
  public String session = "";  // this is the session id returned by the server upon successful login
  private SOAPConnection con = null;
  private MessageFactory mf = null;

  public String service = "";
  public String method = "";
  public String request = "";  // this is what we send to the server
  public String response = "";  // this is what the server return to us

  public SoapHelper(String server)
  {
    this.server = server;
  }

  private String getURI()
  {
    return "https://" + this.server + this.session;
  }

  private SOAPMessage makeMessage(String nodeName, String xmlStr) throws Exception
  {

    SOAPMessage message = this.mf.createMessage();
    SOAPEnvelope envelope = message.getSOAPPart().getEnvelope();

    envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema-instance");
    envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("xsd", "http://www.w3.org/1999/XMLSchema");

    SOAPBody body = envelope.getBody();

    SOAPElement element = body.addChildElement(envelope.createName("ns1:" + this.method));
    element.addAttribute(envelope.createName("xmlns:ns1"), "urn:" + this.service);
    element.addAttribute(envelope.createName("ns1"), "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding");

    SOAPElement ele2 = element.addChildElement(envelope.createName(nodeName));
    ele2.addAttribute(envelope.createName("xsi:type"), "xsd:string");
    ele2.addTextNode(xmlStr);

    message.saveChanges();

    return message;
  }

  private void doConnect()
  {
    try
    {
      SOAPConnectionFactory conFactory = SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
      this.con = conFactory.createConnection();
      this.mf = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
    }
  }

  public boolean doRequest(String service, String method, String xml)
  {
    this.service = service;
    this.method = method;
    this.request = "";
    this.request = xml;

    try
    {
      URL endpoint = new URL(this.getURI());
      SOAPMessage message = this.makeMessage("msgstr", this.request);
      SOAPMessage retval = this.con.call(message, endpoint);
      //extraction du XML en String lisible du message SOAP
      this.response = extractXML(retval);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      this.response = e.getMessage();
    }
    return true;
  }

  private String extractXML(SOAPMessage message) throws Exception
  {

    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    message.writeTo(out);
    String returnxml = new String(out.toByteArray());
    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(returnxml)));
    Element root = document.getDocumentElement();
    Node msg = root.getLastChild();

    return msg.getTextContent();
  }

  private String getSession() throws Exception
  {

    DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
    DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
    Document document = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(this.response)));
    Element root = document.getDocumentElement();

    return root.getAttribute("sessionid");
  }

  public void authenticate(String username, String password)
  {

    this.username = username;
    this.password = password;

    try
    {
      String xml = "<Message messageid='0'><Entity name='REF_LOGIN'>";
      xml += "<Property name='login_cd' value='" + this.username + "' type='string'/>";
      xml += "<Property name='password' value='" + this.password + "' type='string'/>";
      xml += "<Property name='machine_name' value='" + getMachineName() + "' type='string'/>";
      xml += "</Entity></Message>";
      doConnect();
      doRequest("Login", "Authenticate", xml);
      this.session = this.getSession();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
      this.session = e.getMessage();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

IMO, it is unlikely that you can make it significantly faster, and still be safe.

The chances are that *most* of the time is actually consumed in network overheads:

- network latency,
- multiple round trips to establish a secure SSL/TLS connection,
- at least one round trip to login the session,
- at least round trips to send the request and receive the reply,
- (possibly) network congestion, and
- (possibly, but very unlikely) extra network connections, etc to fetch XML schemas.

Now some of this could be *potentially* optimized.  For example:

- The schemas could be cached locally (if they are actually being fetched).
- You could switch to using HTTP rather than HTTPS.
- If you were sending multiple requests to the same service, you could investigate using a persistent connection.

My recommendation would be to use a network monitoring tool on the client side to get real insight into the network traffic.  Then figure out which of the above are contributing to the poor performance.  If the main contributor is network latency (as I suspect) then there is not much you can do about it other than reducing the number of round trips that must be performed.

For the record, I think that it is unlikely that the XML handling is a major contributor to the performance problems.  (But you can verify that using a profiler.)

---

> setting a timeout to zéro something like that?

There is no magic that can make network latency disappear.  Latency is caused by the laws of physics.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. For the XML that I send, I load them from the disk. And I use http connection and it doesn't speed the call.

Comment: I advise you to stop guessing.  1) Use a network monitoring tool.  2) Use a performance profiler.  3) Use results of 1 and 2 to figure out why your client is slow.  4) Based on *that information* ... figure out if optimization is feasible, and whether it will have any real benefit.